# What does this typedef really mean?

Tags: c++, typedef

```
typedef const char* Argv[3+ 8];
```

My guess at this point is the `[3+8]` is creating an anonymous array of type Argv (which is of type const char*).  If I'm right, the anonymous array part is basically meaningless.

Comment: Correct. It's the same as `typedef const char * Argv[];` or even more succinctly, `typedef const char ** Argv;`.

Comment: @DavidHammen, I wouldn't say `const char **` is a perfect substitue: http://liveworkspace.org/code/52a9cbdcc95968a9b2bf18e9488378f5

Comment: @DavidHammen - correct if it's used in a context where it decays. There are contexts where it doesn't. `sizeof(Argv)`, for example.

Comment: @OP, It's readable via the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). Argv is an array of (3+8) pointers to const char (const can be either to left or right of char here), bundled as a typedef.

Comment: Another approach is to think of it as a declaration: `const char *Argv[3+8];` would define `Argv` as an array of 11 pointers to `const char *`. So the typedef defines it as a synonym for that type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It defines `Argv` as a synonym for "array of 11 const char*".

Comment: @jfritz42 - because my arithmetic is broken. Thanks. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

same as

```
const char* somevar[11];
```

or IOW

```
Argv somevar;
```